# Jersey JSONConfiguration FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING - how to skip unwanted entries during deserialization

Tags: jersey

I'm defining pojos for facebook objects, which can be consumed by clients who dont have the capacity to parse JSON. Some of the FB object's data structure is loosely defined, like work

```
"work":[
{"employer":{"id":"xxxxxxxxx","name":"ABC"},
 "location":{"id":"xxxxxxxxx","name":"Philadelphia, Pennsylvania"}
 "position":{"id":"198376496853401","name":"Manager"}
 "with":[{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","name":"Dogbert Smith"}]}
   ]
```

My question is how to skip these objects while deserializing. I'm using

ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

Is there a way I can customize what to deserialize?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I found the solution. Added @JsonIgnoreProperties to the pojo for which I need to ignore some properties. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Added `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to the pojo for which I need to ignore some properties. Works great.